# How to quickly know the indexes in a massive ArrayList of a very large number of strings from this ArrayList in Java?

Tags: java, string, algorithm, arraylist

Suppose that I have a collection of 50 million different strings in a Java ArrayList. Let `foo` be a set of 40 million arbitrarily chosen (but fixed) strings from the previous collection. I want to know the index of every string in `foo` in the ArrayList.

An obvious way to do this would be to iterate through the whole ArrayList until we found a match for the first string in `foo`, then for the second one and so on. However, this solution would take an extremely long time (considering also that 50 million was an arbitrary large number that I picked for the example, the collection could be in the order of hundreds of millions or even billions but this is given from the beginning and remains constant).

I thought then of using a Hashtable of fixed size 50 million in order to determine the index of a given string in `foo` using `someStringInFoo.hashCode()`. However, from my understanding of Java's Hashtable, it seems that this will fail if there are collisions as calling `hashCode()` will produce the same index for two different strings.

Lastly, I thought about first sorting the ArrayList with the `sort(List<T> list)` in Java's Collections and then using  `binarySearch(List<? extends T> list,T key,Comparator<? super T> c)` to obtain the index of the term. Is there a more efficient solution than this or is this as good as it gets?

Comment: "it seems that this will fail if there are collisions as calling hashCode() will produce the same index for two different strings. " - Nowhere does it say that different keys can't have the same hashcode.

Comment: If you need your solution to scale to billions of entries, you should be considering a database solution rather than an array or HashMap. A Java array has no more than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` entries.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan that is true, but for now I am dealing with around 1 billion and a half entries at most. I will consider a database approach later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need additional data structure that is optimized for searching strings. It will map string to it's index. The idea is that you iterate your original list populating your data structure and then iterate your set, performing searches in that data structure.

What structure should you choose?

There are three options worth considering:

- Java's HashMap
- [TRIE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)
- Java's [IdentityHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html)

The first option is simple to implement but provides not the best possible performance. But still, it's population time O(N * R) is better than sorting the list, which is O(R * N * log N). Searching time is better then in sorted String list (amortized O(R) compared to O(R log N).
Where R is the average length of your strings.

The second option is always good for maps of strings, providing guaranteed population time for your case of O(R * N) and guaranteed worst-case searching time of O(R).  The only disadvantage of it is that there is no out-of-box implementation in Java standard libraries.

The third option is a bit tricky and suitable only for your case. In order to make it work you need to ensure that strings from the first list are literally used in second list (are the same objects). Using IdentityHashMap eliminates String's equals cost (the R above), as IdentityHashMap compares strings by address, taking only O(1). Population cost will be amortized O(N) and search cost amortized O(1). So this solution provides the best performance and out-of-box implementation. However please note that this solution will work only if there are no duplicates in the original list.

If you have any questions please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Java Hashtable with no problems. According to the Java Documentation "in the case of a "hash collision", a single bucket stores multiple entries, which must be searched sequentially."

I think you have a misconception on how hash tables work. Hash collisions do NOT ruin the implementation. A hash table is simply an array of linked-lists. Each key goes through a hash function to determine the index in the array which the element will be placed. If a hash collision occurs, the element will be placed at the end of the linked-list at the index in the hash-table array. See link below for diagram.

[image: hash table]